# solution to PDE: $z(x+z)z_x-y(y+z)z_y=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I wondered how to solve this PDE, but I failed to find a method:
$$z(x+z)z_x-y(y+z)z_y=0$$
$$z(1,y)=\sqrt y$$
where $x(t), y(t), z(x(t), y(t)).$
Method that I tried to use gives this system:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\frac{dx}{dt}=z(x+z) \\ \frac{dy}{dt}=-y(y+z)\end{array}\right.$$
Now I don't know how to eliminate z from right side to get a general solution in form:
$$z=\omega(\phi(x,y))$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [General solution to a first-order partial differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2767077/general-solution-to-a-first-order-partial-differential-equation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dz}{dt}=0$ , letting $z(0)=z_0$ , we have $z=z_0$

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=z(x+z)=z_0(x+z_0)$ , letting $x(0)=0$ , we have $x=z_0(e^{z_0t}-1)=z(e^{zt}-1)$

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=y(y+z)=y(y+z_0)$ , we have

$\dfrac{y}{y+z_0}=f(z_0)e^{z_0t}$

$\dfrac{y}{y+z}=f(z)\dfrac{x+z}{z}$

$\dfrac{yz}{(x+z)(y+z)}=f(z)$

$z(1,y)=\sqrt y$ :

$f(\sqrt y)=\dfrac{y\sqrt y}{(1+\sqrt y)(y+\sqrt y)}$

$f(y)=\dfrac{y^3}{(1+y)(y^2+y)}=\dfrac{y^2}{(y+1)^2}$

$\therefore\dfrac{yz}{(x+z)(y+z)}=\dfrac{z^2}{(z+1)^2}$

$y(z+1)^2=z(x+z)(y+z)$