# General solution to a first-order partial differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

$$
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle u(x+u)\frac {\partial }{\partial } - y(y+u)\frac {\partial }{\partial }  = 0 \\
u=\sqrt y ,x =1
\end{cases}
$$

my idea: Can we solve by the method : 
$$\frac {x}{u(+u )} =  \frac{y}{-y( +u)}$$

Comment: First check if the PDE is $$u(x+u)\frac {\partial }{\partial } - y(y+u)\frac {\partial }{\partial }  = 0$$ or is $$x(x+u)\frac {\partial }{\partial } - y(y+u)\frac {\partial }{\partial }  = 0$$ In both cases $\frac {x}{+u } =  \frac{y}{-y( +u)}$ is not correct : $u$ or $x$ is missing in the first denominator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer......yes.....It is my mistake.....u(x+u) du/dx - y(y+u)du/dy = 0 is right.....///

Answer (score 2):

This problem is solvable by using the method of characteristics. Letting $t$ be the characteristic coordinate, we obtain this system of differential equations
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = u(x+u), \quad\frac{dy}{dt} = -y(y+u), \quad\frac{du}{dt} = 0$$
We can easily solve for $u$ provided the initial condition that $u(x(0),y(0))=\sqrt{y_0}$,
$$u = \sqrt{y_0}$$
Plugging this result into the differential equation for $x$ and integrating gives
$$x(t)=ce^{\sqrt{y_0}t}-\sqrt{y_0}$$
Using the initial condition that $x(0)=1$ gives
$$x(t) = \left(1+\sqrt{y_0}\right)e^{\sqrt{y_0}t}-\sqrt{y_0}$$
Upon solving the differential equation for $y$, we see after applying the initial condition $y(0)=y_0$ (and after some algebra) that
$$y(t)=\frac{y_0}{\left(1+\sqrt{y_0}\right)e^{\sqrt{y_0}t}-\sqrt{y_0}}$$
We can rewrite the equation for $y$ simply in terms of $u$ and $x$ thereby inverting the equation and eliminating the characteristic coordinate
$$y=\frac{u^2}{x}$$
Rearrangement gives the simple solution to the complicated-appearing PDE
$$\boxed{u(x,y) = \sqrt{xy}}$$
Plugging this back into the original PDE verifies the result. May the Fourth be with you.

Comment: Thank a lots for your answer /// I was difficult to solve this problem as I haven't  calculated like this problem for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
u(x+u)u_x-y(y+u)u_y & = & 0\\
u_x dx + u_y dy & = & du
\end{array}
\right.
$$

we conclude $u(x,y) = C_0$ along the characteristic curves and

$$
\frac{dx}{x+C_0}= - \frac{C_0dy}{y(y+C_0)}
$$

Integrating both sides

$$
\ln(C_0+x)+\ln(y)-\ln(y+C_0) = C_1
$$

From now on please follow the LutzL comments below.

---

(LutzL copy from comment)
$$
\frac{(x+C_0)y}{y+C_0}=\pm e^{C_1}=C_2=\phi(C_0),
$$ 
as the solution is a one-parameter family of characteristic curves, that is there is only one degree of freedom between the two integration constants. Then insert the initial condition $C_0=u(1,y)=\sqrt{y}=t$, $y=t^2$, to get 
$$
\phi(t)=\frac{(1+t)t^2}{t^2+t}=t
$$ 
so that (using again that $C_0=u(x,y)$)
$$
(x+C_0)y=C_0(y+C_0)\iff xy=C_0^2=u(x,y)^2.
$$

Comment: For the global solution you have to start with $C_0=\phi(C_2)$ or similar, in general form $\Phi(C_0,C_2)=0$ as defining relation of $\phi$ as this function connects the constants of the characteristic curve. As you do it, you mix variables and constants, which will give a wrong result.

Comment: Integration of $$\frac{dx}{x+C_0}=-\frac{C_0dy}{y(y+C_0)}=\frac{dy}{y+C_0}-\frac{dy}{y}$$ leads to $$\ln|x+C_0|+C_1=\ln|y+C_0|-\ln|y|\implies \frac{(x+C_0)y}{y+C_0}=C_2=\phi(C_0),$$ then insert $C_0=u(1,y)=\sqrt{y}=t$, $y=t^2$, to get $$\phi(t)=\frac{(1+t)t^2}{t^2+t}=t$$ so that $$(x+C_0)y=C_0(y+C_0)\iff xy=C_0^2=u(x,y)^2.$$

Comment: Your approach is nice and clean. I will refer it as the answer conclusion. Thanks.

Comment: If you feel bad about getting points for the mixed solution, mark the answer as "community". For my part, I do not feel that it is necessary.